# Tweepy geo search keeps returning tweets far outside of range

Tags: python, api, geolocation, tweepy, tweets

Please help! I am trying complete a geo specific query search using free tweepy API. I realised that the tweet coordinates/place being returned were still from all across the globe. Even when I simplify the code to investigate, the geo still wont work:

```
# Get auth - deleter is a function I made to format .txt into string, note the appauth not oauth.

def startup(loc):
    consumer_secret = deleter(open(loc[0],'r').read(),'\n')
    consumer_key = deleter(open(loc[1],'r').read(),'\n')
    auth = tweepy.AppAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True,
                   wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)
    if (not api):
        print ("Can't Authenticate"),sys.exit(-1)
    return api

# Keys
loc = ['consumer_scret.txt', 'api.txt']
api = startup(loc)

# Search parameters
query = "lockdown"
gg = "5.29126,52.132633,10km"


results = api.search(q=query,geo=gg, count = 100)
for tweet in results:
   print(tweet.id,tweet.geo,tweet.place,tweet.coordinates)
```

- No matter how small the search radius, 100 tweets are always returned
- If I search in Bangladesh with a radius of 10 mi, tweets with place/coordinates from places as far as the US are returned.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think your geo parameter is being ignored. The parameter name to pass to the search api is `geocode`, not `geo`. Try this:

```
results = api.search(q=query, geocode=gg, count=100)
```

When I run that with a search radius as small as 10km I get no results. If I expand the radius to 1000km I get a lot more.

**Reference:** [API.search](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/api.html#API.search)

Comment: I have just realised I was using an expired parameter. Thanks for your help!